# Upstream Dependency Conflict Installing Sqlite3

Tags: sqlite, npm, dependencies

I am trying to install sqlite3 as it's an unmet dependency in my project. When installing it via npm I get the following error text:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: grunt-js-beautify@0.1.4
npm ERR! Found: grunt@1.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/grunt
npm ERR!   peer grunt@">=0.4.5" from grunt-contrib-clean@1.1.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/grunt-contrib-clean
npm ERR!     dev grunt-contrib-clean@"^1.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer grunt@">=0.4.0" from grunt-contrib-concat@1.0.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/grunt-contrib-concat
npm ERR!     dev grunt-contrib-concat@"^1.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (grunt-contrib-jshint, grunt-jsbeautifier, ...)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer grunt@"~0.4.5" from grunt-js-beautify@0.1.4
npm ERR! node_modules/grunt-js-beautify
npm ERR!   dev grunt-js-beautify@"^0.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: grunt@0.4.5
npm ERR! node_modules/grunt
npm ERR!   peer grunt@"~0.4.5" from grunt-js-beautify@0.1.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/grunt-js-beautify
npm ERR!     dev grunt-js-beautify@"^0.1.4" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2024-02-04T21_45_32_183Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2024-02-04T21_45_32_183Z-debug-0.log
```

I'm having trouble deciphering where the conflict is specifically, and what I should do about it. I've tried installing both via the `--force` and the install `--legacy-peer-deps` commands to no success. Do I need to install an older version of grunt?

I've also included the relevant npm packages list below:

```
npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! missing: sqlite3@^3.1.9, required by layouts@1.0.0
├── bignumber@1.1.0
├── bluebird@3.5.0
├── body-parser@1.17.2
├── bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.6
├── express@4.15.3
├── grunt-contrib-clean@1.1.0
├── grunt-contrib-concat@1.0.1
├── grunt-contrib-copy@1.0.0
├── grunt-contrib-jshint@1.1.0
├── grunt-contrib-uglify@3.3.0
├── grunt-js-beautify@0.1.4
├── grunt-jsbeautifier@0.2.13
├── grunt-jslint@1.1.15
├── grunt-prettier@0.4.0
├── grunt-prettify@0.4.0
├── grunt-rollup@9.0.0
├── grunt@1.0.2
├── mariasql@0.2.6
├── mysql@2.14.1
├── node-redis@0.1.7
├── q-sqlite3@0.1.3
├── redis@2.8.0
├── socket.io@2.0.3
├── sqlite@2.8.0
├── UNMET DEPENDENCY sqlite3@^3.1.9
├── topojson@ extraneous
├── underscore@1.8.3
└── websocket.io@0.2.1
```